# Java, JAX-WS I cant understand for what are some class generated by wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, jax-ws

I have some problem with understanding for what are 3 class generated by wsimport tool from JAX-WS API for client-side application.

Have class with @WebService like below:

```
@WebService
public class HelloService
{
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHelloTo(String name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

I publish it by code:

```
Endpoint.publish(address, new HelloService());
```

When I genrate client's stubs by wsimport like this:

```
wsimport -p client.hello -keep -Xnocompile http://localhost/service-name?wsdl
```

I get files like here:

```
 HelloService.java
 HelloServiceService.java
 ObjectFactory.java
 package-info.java
 SayHelloTo.java
 SayHelloToResponse.java
```

The problem is I dont understand, and I cant find answer for what are class: ObjectFactory, SayHelloTo, SayHelloToResponse. I dont understand because when I del this files the clients app works correct. First i thought it is using by JAX-WS engine to generate SOAPMessage but when i del it and run client app it breaks my mind.

Client code is simple as possibile:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        HelloServiceService service = new HelloServiceService();
        HelloService helloService = service.getHelloServicePort();


        System.out.println(helloService.sayHelloTo("Adam"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need get more understang on what WSDL stands for as well as its parts?

- `SayHelloTo` and `SayHelloToResponse` correspond to Request/Response message definition.
  (you must have them there with appropriate XSD definition)
  as long as your code does not use them - code works without them.
- `HelloServiceService` in your case is a WebService stub from service definition in WSDL (that why wsimport appended a name with "Service"
- `HelloService` is binding port stub from the WSDL you can see as you get it by calling 
  'getHelloServicePort();'
- `ObjectFactory` is JAXB optional helper class with methods to create new instances of objects according to XSD definition. It is much better (and recommeded) to use rather than `SayHelloTo request = new SayHelloTo();`

BTW
it is not complete answer and I guess I missed some more details ... but maybe it will help you to start.

UPD:
Look at your WSDL there must be something like (not neccessary exactly but kind of)

```
<service name="HelloService">
  <port name="HelloService" ...>
    ...
  </port>
</service>

<portType name="HelloService">
  <operation name="sayHelloTo">      
    <input name="sayHelloTo" message="tns:sayHelloTo" />
    <output name="sayHelloToResponse" message="tns:sayHelloToResponse" />
  </operation>
</portType>

<message name="sayHelloTo">
  <part name="RequestMessage" element="SayHelloTo" />
</message>
<message name="sayHelloToResponse">
  <part name="ResponseMessage" element="SayHelloToResponse" />
</message>
```

in the Schema part could be something like:

```
<xsd:element name="SayHelloTo" type="{some type definition}"/>
<xsd:element name="SayHelloToResponse" type="{some type definition}"/>
```

or type can be defined right in those elements ("Russian Doll" structure) 
This is a point from where `SayHelloTo.java` and `SayHelloToResponse.java` come.

But your Webservice implementation at

```
@WebMethod
public String sayHelloTo(String name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

does not use those classes, so when you delete them manually nothing happens...

At least it is how I understand it...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Is it possible, that you could explaing with more details this part:

"SayHelloTo and SayHelloToResponse correspond to Request/Response message definition. (you must have them there with appropriate XSD definition) as long as your code does not use them - code works without them."

I know what is XSD for WSDL file, so you dant have to explain that point and I know that classes are map of this XSD Schema.